# How to write custom removePunctuation() function to better deal with Unicode chars?

Tags: r, unicode, text-mining, tm

In the source code of the tm text-mining R-package, in file [transform.R](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/transform.R?view=markup&root=tm), there is the `removePunctuation()` function, currently defined as:

```
function(x, preserve_intra_word_dashes = FALSE)
{
    if (!preserve_intra_word_dashes)
        gsub("[[:punct:]]+", "", x)
    else {
        # Assume there are no ASCII 1 characters.
        x <- gsub("(\\w)-(\\w)", "\\1\1\\2", x)
        x <- gsub("[[:punct:]]+", "", x)
        gsub("\1", "-", x, fixed = TRUE)
    }
}
```

I need to parse and mine some abstracts from a science conference (fetched from their website as UTF-8). The abstracts contain some unicode characters that need to be removed, particularly at word boundaries. There are the usual ASCII punctuation characters, but also a few Unicode Dashes, Unicode Quotes, Math Symbols...

There are also URLs in the text, and there the punctuation the intra-word punctuation characters need to be preserved. tm's built-in `removePunctuation()` function is too radical.

So I need a custom `removePunctuation()` function to do removal according to my requirements.

My custom Unicode function looks like this now, but it does not work as expected. I am using R only rarely, so getting things done in R takes some time, even for the simplest tasks.

**My function:**

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, rmPunc =  function(x){ 
# lookbehinds 
# need to be careful to specify fixed-width conditions 
# so that it can be used in lookbehind

x <- gsub('(.*?)(?<=^[[:punct:]’“”:±</>]{5})([[:alnum:]])'," \\2", x, perl=TRUE) ;
x <- gsub('(.*?)(?<=^[[:punct:]’“”:±</>]{4})([[:alnum:]])'," \\2", x, perl=TRUE) ;
x <- gsub('(.*?)(?<=^[[:punct:]’“”:±</>]{3})([[:alnum:]])'," \\2", x, perl=TRUE) ;
x <- gsub('(.*?)(?<=^[[:punct:]’“”:±</>]{2})([[:alnum:]])'," \\2", x, perl=TRUE) ;
x <- gsub('(.*?)(?<=^[[:punct:]’“”:±</>])([[:alnum:]])'," \\2", x, perl=TRUE) ; 
# lookaheads (can use variable-width conditions) 
x <- gsub('(.*?)(?=[[:alnum:]])([[:punct:]’“”:±]+)$',"\1 ", x, perl=TRUE) ;

# remove all strings that consist *only* of punct chars 
gsub('^[[:punct:]’“”:±</>]+$',"", x, perl=TRUE) ;

}
```

It does not work as expected. I think, it doesn't do anything at all.
The punctuation is still inside the terms-document matrix, see:

```
 head(Terms(tdm), n=30)

  [1] "<></>"                      "---"                       
  [3] "--,"                        ":</>"                      
  [5] ":()"                        "/)."                       
  [7] "/++"                        "/++,"                      
  [9] "..,"                        "..."                       
 [11] "...,"                       "..)"                       
 [13] "“”,"                        "(|)"                       
 [15] "(/)"                        "(.."                       
 [17] "(..,"                       "()=(|=)."                  
 [19] "(),"                        "()."                       
 [21] "(&)"                        "++,"                       
 [23] "(0°"                        "0.001),"                   
 [25] "0.003"                      "=0.005)"                   
 [27] "0.006"                      "=0.007)"                   
 [29] "000km"                      "0.01)" 
...
```

**So my questions are:**

1. Why doesn't the call to my function(){} have the desired effect? How can my
   function be improved?
2. Are Unicode regex pattern classes such as if
   `\P{ASCII}` or `\P{PUNCT}` supported in R's perl-compatible regular
   expressions? I think they aren't (by default) by [PCRE:](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html): " Only the support for various Unicode properties with \p is incomplete, though the most important ones are supported."

Comment: Try `iconv(mytext, to='ASCII', sub=' ')` to replace the unicode characters with spaces.

Comment: I think the first to do thing to improve your function is to give us a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I like Susana's answer it is breaking the Corpus in newer versions of *tm* (No longer a PlainTextDocument and destroying the meta)

You will get a *list* and the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : 
no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Using

```
tm_map(your_corpus, PlainTextDocument)
```

will give you back your corpus but with broken $meta (in particular document ids will be missing.

**Solution**

Use *content_transformer*

```
toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x,pattern)
    gsub(pattern," ", x))
your_corpus <- tm_map(your_corpus,toSpace,"„")
```

*Source:*
Hands-On Data Science with R,
Text Mining,
Graham.Williams@togaware.com http://onepager.togaware.com/

### Update

This function removes everything that is not alpha numeric (i.e. UTF-8 emoticons etc.)

```
removeNonAlnum <- function(x){
  gsub("[^[:alnum:]^[:space:]]","",x)
}
```

Comment: Did it, but I still have the unicodes \u0093, \u0094, ..., \u0097 in the term document matrix. How could i - if not else but manually - restrict the corpus? I.e. add them to stopwords or so?

Comment: I took me a couple of years to refine my answer:

removeNonAlnum <- function(x){
gsub("[^[:alnum:]^[:space:]]","",x)
}

I removes everything that is not a character or number (I haven't come up with a regex for UTF-8 smilies :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, custom function was not working, but actually the first line below has to be added

Regards

Susana

```
replaceExpressions <- function(x) UseMethod("replaceExpressions", x)

replaceExpressions.PlainTextDocument <- replaceExpressions.character  <- function(x) {
    x <- gsub(".", " ", x, ignore.case =FALSE, fixed = TRUE)
    x <- gsub(",", " ", x, ignore.case =FALSE, fixed = TRUE)
    x <- gsub(":", " ", x, ignore.case =FALSE, fixed = TRUE)
    return(x)
}

notes_pre_clean <- tm_map(notes, replaceExpressions, useMeta = FALSE)
```