# How to write custom control functions for text mining in R

Tags: r, nlp, tm

I have a text data set, including different topics, that is badly written, with lots of words stuck together. I found a way to break the "long terms" into adequate words and I have crated a data table like this (only showing rows useful for this example):

`>wordMap[1:4]
                longTerm                    words
1:        linedconcealed          lined,concealed
2:     jacketcontrasting       jacket,contrasting
3:     spandexspecialist       spandex,specialist
4: inchescmmidweightsemi inchescm,mid,weight,semi`

bear in mind that the `words` column is in itself a list of words

```
>class(wordMap$words)
"list"
>wordMap$words[1]
[[1]]
[1] "lined"     "concealed"
```

with this data table I would like to create a control function to be passed to the function `tm_map` within the `tm` package. Based on this post [custom removePunctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281282/how-to-write-custom-removepunctuation-function-to-better-deal-with-unicode-cha) I built this function:

```
>mapWords <- function(x) UseMethod("mapWords", x)
>mapWords.PlainTextDocument <- mapWords.character <- function(x) {

    if (x %in% wordMap$longTerm) {
        i <- which(x == wordMap$longTerm)
        x=wordMap$words[[i]]
    } 

    return(x)
}
```

I tried this function with the following Corpus:

`testC[[1]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
alice + olivia black wool  blend  jacketcontrasting weave, padded shoulders, leather trims, fully linedconcealed hook fastenings through frontfabric  % wool, % cotton; fabric  % leather; fabric  % rayon, % nylon, % elastane; lining  % polyester, % spandexspecialist cleanlength shoulder to hem   inchescmmidweightsemi fitted stylethis style runs true to sizemodel is '"cm and wears a size small`

There are four "longTerms" which are the four examples included in the data table above (so the problem is reproducible). When I run `tm_map` I get the following error:

```
>tm_map(testC, mapWords)
```

`Warning message:
In if (x %in% wordMap$longTerm) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

which is pretty clear. The condition is matched more than once. However, I though the map function worked on a "token basis", passing to the control function tokens one by one. Usually, my customized control functions use `gsub` or similar, so they are coded different that my `mapWords` function above. Here is an example of one control function that works:

```
rmRepeatLetters <- function(str) gsub('([[:alpha:]])\\1{2,}', '\\1', str)
```

Overall, I would like to know how should I code the `mapWords` function so I could pass it to `tm_map`.

Note that I could do this exercise directly on text:

```
>testT <- as.character(testC[[1]])
>terms <- paste(as.character(unlist(sapply(unlist(strsplit(testT, " ")), function(x) mapWords(x)))), collapse = " ")
>terms
```

`"alice + olivia black wool  blend  jacket contrasting weave, padded shoulders, leather trims, fully lined concealed hook fastenings through frontfabric  % wool, % cotton; fabric  % leather; fabric  % rayon, % nylon, % elastane; lining  % polyester, % spandex specialist cleanlength shoulder to hem   inchescm mid weight semi fitted stylethis style runs true to sizemodel is '\"cm and wears a size small"`

However, I would like to know if there is a way to build a customized control function to break the long terms in the Corpus itself.

Thanks in advance for your time!