# Still have punctuation issues after removePunctuation function

Tags: r, text, plot, nlp, tm

I have used the removePuncutation from the "tm" package in R on a Term Document Matrix. For some reason I am still left with strange characters in my plot of the letters versus their proportion in a corpus I've analyzed.

Below is the code I used to clean the corpus:

```
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/|@|\\|")
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
freq <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
words <- dtm %>%as.matrix %>%colnames %>% (function(x) x[nchar(x) < 20])
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
words %>%str_split("") %>%sapply(function(x) x[-1]) %>%unlist%>%dist_tab %>%mutate(Letter=factor(toupper(interval),levels=toupper(interval[order(freq)]))) %>%ggplot(aes(Letter, weight=percent))+geom_bar()+coord_flip()+ylab("Proportion")+scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 12,2),label=function(x) paste0(x, "%"),expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0,12))
```

I'm left with the following plot:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what went wrong here.

Comment: Try to read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281282/how-to-write-custom-removepunctuation-function-to-better-deal-with-unicode-cha

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. I get the exact same plot.

Comment: Did you try to do multiple toSpace calls? What you are specifying is that this string "/|@|\\|" should be transformed to a space. Not the individual characters or combination of characters.